# como Insertar un tr en la posicion 0 en una tabla con jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

tengo un tabla similar a esta:

```js
$("#nuevo").click(function(){
tr="<tr><td>Nuevo</td><td>1</td></tr>";
  $("#tabla").append(tr);
});
```

```css
table tr td{
border:1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla" style="border:1px solid #000">
<tr>
<td>Nombre
</td>
<td>Nro
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button id="nuevo">nuevo</button>
```

En la cual se añaden filas en la parte inferior de la tabla.

Mi pregunta es:

> Como inserto esa nueva fila en la parte superior de la tabla?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En vez de utilizar `append()` o `prepend()` deberías utilizar la acción `after()`. Las dos primeras opciones necesitas meterlas en un elemento padre para que funcione, pero con la tercera puedes añadirlos después del elemento que deseas.

```js
var num = 1;
$("#nuevo").click(function(){
  tr="<tr><td>Nuevo</td><td>"+num+"</td></tr>";
  num++;
  $("#tabla tr:first").after(tr);
});
```

```css
table tr td{
border:1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla" style="border:1px solid #000">
  <tr>
    <td>Nombre
    </td>
    <td>Nro
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="nuevo">nuevo</button>
```

Comment: 7 segundos de diferencia entre tu respuesta y la mía y son la misma (hasta con el contador) *Great minds think alike*

Comment: están bien las dos respuestas la verdad, y he usado las dos y funconan bine, eso si hay qie tener claro que es lo que se quiere jaja

Answer (score 3):

Es importante utilizar el plugin .on() asociado al DOM ya que te permite que los elementos generados dinámicamente reciban esa función por el evento indicado, es decir todos los elementos con ID nuevo generarán esa acción al hacerle click, aunque el #nuevo sea cargado dinámicamente.

```
$(document).on("click","#nuevo",function(){
  $("#selector-de-la-tabla").prepend("<tr>Contenido del TR</>");
});

<button id="nuevo">nuevo</button>
```